# How to browse the data on google's filestore server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-filestore

I have created a `nfs-server` using Google Cloud's `FileStore` and have linked it to a kubernetes engine. I would like to know how to access the stored data on `FileStore`?

Thanks, Look forward to the suggestions.

Comment: It's 2023, and I definitely still want an answer to this question, if somebody can provide one!

Answer (score 0):

You can only get operation information using the gcloud tool. To use the gcloud tool, you must either install the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) or use the Cloud Shell that is built into the Cloud Console.

You can get a list of Filestore operations by running the operations list command:

```
gcloud filestore operations list
    --[project=project-id] \
    --[zone=zone]
```

where:

- project-id is the project ID of the Cloud project that contains the
  Filestore instance. You can skip this flag if the Filestore instance
  is in the gcloud default project. You can set the default project by
  running:

  **gcloud config set project project-id**
- zone is the zone where the Filestore instance resides. Run the gcloud
  filestore zones list command to get a list of supported zones. You
  can skip this flag if the Filestore instance is in the gcloud default
  zone. You can set the default zone by running:

  **gcloud config set filestore/zone zone**

The command returns a response similar to the following example:

```
OPERATION_NAME                                           LOCATION        TYPE    TARGET   STATUS  CREATE_TIME          DURATION
operation-1505929956434-559a2a41c217c-231e6a94-a4b6a803  us-central1-c   create  nfs1     DONE    2017-09-20T17:52:36  <1S
operation-1505931180862-559a2ed176d0d-a0d70ae0-35ef2e71  europe-west1-b  create  nfs2     DONE    2017-09-20T18:13:00  <1S
```

You can get details of a specific Filestore operation by running the operations describe command:

```
gcloud filestore operations describe operation-name \
    --[project=project-id] \
    --[zone=zone]
```

where:

- operation-name is the name of the Filestore operation. Use the
  operations list command to get a list of operation names.
- project-id is the project ID of the Cloud project that contains the
  Filestore instance. You can skip this flag if the Filestore instance
  is in the gcloud default project. You can set the default project by
  running:

  **gcloud config set project project-id**
- zone is the zone where the Filestore instance resides. Run the gcloud
  filestore zones list command to get a list of supported zones. You
  can skip this flag if the Filestore instance is in the gcloud default
  zone. You can set the default zone by running:

  **gcloud config set filestore/zone zone**

The command returns a response similar to the following:

```
done: true
metadata:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.common.OperationMetadata
  apiVersion: v1beta1
  createTime: '2017-10-09T22:18:09.347400Z'
  endTime: '2017-10-09T22:20:04.392199183Z'
  target: projects/filestore-test/locations/us-central1-c/instances/filer3
  verb: delete
name: projects/filestore-test/locations/us-central1-c/operations/operation-1507587489330-55b2490c4f394-faece090-1c0e16db
```

Getting operation information document: https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/getting-operation-information

Here is also how to monitor your Filestore instances and set up alerts for low disk space and low backups quota.

You can monitor Filestore instances using [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring).

Comment: This answer is useful, but it does not answer the question.